# Magento Bundles (Long MYSQL Query)

Tags: mysql, ce-1.6.2.0

I have been working with magento, our store only uses bundle products, and as we have started to have a large amount of data (10,000 simple products) (around 1500 bundle products)

I Have noticed that saving and requesting has become a lot larger, when I have ran the Mysql request check I can see then when selecting 'bundle items' in the product screen it will request every single, single product within the database.

I was wondering if anyone has come across the same problem or issue?

**UPDATE**

I have also installed a basic version of magento 1.6.2 which we are using, and copied the data base to see if it was a module confliction, still the bundle is searching for 10,000 entity i'ds before proceeding to the next page.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing all of the specifics about your catalog and seeing debug data myself it would be very very difficult to give you specific advice. Your issue may likely be too broad for us to diagnose via Magento.SE. A few thoughts, though, to get you on the right path:

- Bundles are comprised of other products, and specifically their pricing and weight can be a function of their selections' prices and weights. If all of your simple products are also found in bundles it may be conceivable that, if all bundles are requested, then all simples are also requested.
- If you have any customization in the Catalog > Products view at all this may lead to unforeseen consequences. (For example, I've seen a certain product matrix plugin that loaded all attributes including gallery attributes, for all product types even if they weren't being used in the grid).
- When viewing a subset of your bundles (in the grid view for instance) you have the ability by default to view 20, 50, 100, 200 at a time; this pagination should prevent an excessive amount of data from being loaded. If there is evidence still that all products are being loaded even when only 20 are being displayed I would begin debugging by methodically disabling your local modules one-at-a-time until the issue subsides. Likely there's a local module that is doing a `$product->getCollection()->load()` which is fetching all products in that view.

For specific debugging advice (disabling local modules, for instance) see the following answer which gives step-by-step advice on how to proceed systematically when diagnosing these types of issues:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/429/336

Comment: Hi Phil, Thanks for the reply,

This isnt a result of custom modules, this is the base installation of Magento: 1.6.2 CE

I can provide the mysql txt file but all you will see is THE QUERY searching every single simple product in preperation for the next page (and getting all entity i'ds) which was over 10,000. (This is where you select what simple products should be in the bundle).

Im starting to think it might be an oversite in the design of magento's bundle system.

Comment: Having managed 800k+ SKU installs and having 100's of thousands of bundles, I haven't run up against this. I don't doubt your debugging expertise, but are you absolutely, 100% sure that this is a _base_ install, with absolutely no customizations?

Comment: This is what im trying to get to the bottom of, ive compared some part of the admin bundle creation files, and compared it to a normal fresh install without any changes. 

and would you be able to test on your server? this is the process to get the same results I am,

1. Go to your mage store with high number of simple products - 2. create a bundle product
3. when you click 'bundle items' on the left hand side
At that point the page then queries all simple products and entity id's.
Would you reccomend me doing a fresh install on dev, and just copy the DB?

Comment: Correct. Follow the debug guide posted above to the T. After that step, if still not resolved, install a fresh 1.6.2 (downloaded directly from Magento.com) and point that install's local.xml at your older database.

Comment: Updated question